# Java FX Screen Updates Freezing during Animation

Tags: java, multithreading, animation, javafx

Can any of you FX Gurus tell me why this code appears to freeze FX screen updates? The loop is continuing to run in the animation thread, but after a while the screen stops updating.

I know, by the way, that using Thread.sleep in this way might upset some people, but this is code for students in an intro course to allow them to create animations without doing any event handling.

The exercise for students is to convert the animation to make it bounce an array of 100's of balls moving in random directions. After the conversion, the freeze tends to come much earlier than with a single ball.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the main class...

```
package week6code;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Bouncing Balls exercise starter
 *
 * @author Sam Scott
 */
public class BouncingBalls extends Application {

    /**
     * Sets up the stage and starts the main thread. Your drawing code should
     * NOT go here.
     *
     * @param stage The first stage
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Bouncing Balls!"); // window title here
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 300); // canvas size here
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // This code starts a "thread" which will run your animation
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> animate(gc));
        t.start();
    }

    /**
     * Animation thread. This is where you put your animation code.
     *
     * @param gc The drawing surface
     */
    public void animate(GraphicsContext gc) {
        // YOUR CODE HERE!

        // intial positions and speeds
        Ball ball = new Ball(100, 50, -1, -1, 10, Color.RED);

        while (true) // loop forever
        {
            // draw screen 
            gc.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
            gc.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
            ball.draw(gc);

            // moving
            ball.moveOneStep();

            // bouncing
            if (ball.getX() <= 0 || ball.getX() >= 400 - (ball.getSize() - 1)) {
                ball.bounceX();
            }
            if (ball.getY() <= 0 || ball.getY() >= 300 - (ball.getSize() - 1)) {
                ball.bounceY();
            }

            // pause
            pause(1000 / 60);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Use this method instead of Thread.sleep(). It handles the possible
     * exception by catching it, because re-throwing it is not an option in this
     * case.
     *
     * @param duration Pause time in milliseconds.
     */
    public static void pause(int duration) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Exits the app completely when the window is closed. This is necessary to
     * kill the animation thread.
     */
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Launches the app
     *
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here's the Ball class.

```
package week6solutions;

import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

/**
 * An example of an object that can draw and move itself.
 *
 * @author Sam Scott
 */
public class Ball {

    private double x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed;
    private final int size;
    private final Color c;

    /**
     * Creates a Ball instance.
     *
     * @param x Initial x position (left)
     * @param y Initial y position (top)
     * @param xSpeed Number of pixels to move horizontally in each step
     * (negative for left, positive for right)
     * @param ySpeed Number of pixels to move vertically in each step (negative
     * for up, positive for down)
     * @param size Diameter of ball
     * @param c Color of ball
     */
    public Ball(double x, double y, double xSpeed, double ySpeed, int size, Color c) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
        this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
        this.size = size;
        this.c = c;
    }

    /**
     * Increment x and y using the values of xSpeed and ySpeed
     */
    public void moveOneStep() {
        x += xSpeed;
        y += ySpeed;
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the x direction by multiplying it by -1
     */
    public void bounceX() {
        xSpeed *= -1;
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the y direction by multiplying it by -1
     */
    public void bounceY() {
        ySpeed *= -1;
    }

    /**
     * Draw the ball in its current location on a Graphics object
     *
     * @param g The GraphicsContext object to draw on
     */
    public void draw(GraphicsContext g) {
        g.setFill(c);
        g.fillOval((int) Math.round(x), (int) Math.round(y), size, size);
    }

    /**
     * @return the current x location
     */
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * @return the current y location
     */
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * @return the size of the ball
     */
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

}
```

Comment: The best route is to use something from `JavaFX's` [`Animation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) class. My rule of thumb is that when the task is long-running but not `GUI` related, use `Thread`. When the task is long-running and makes use of the `GUI`, used `Animation`.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/javafx/javafx-animated-ball-example/

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far, but as I stated, I'm not looking for the "right" way to do it. I have chosen this method because it is the right thing to do for my students at this moment in their education (they're comfortable with loops and learning basic OO but have not yet been exposed to event-driven programming). But I'm puzzled as to why it seems to freeze FX screen updates after a while.

Comment: Just ran your code. It's running fine on my machine. How long did it take for you to experience freezing?

Comment: Oh,  maybe your problem is due to no updating the `GUI` from a `Thread` using `Platform.runlater();`.

Comment: Thanks, Sedrick. That's fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

I still don't understand why you insist on teaching to do this the wrong way if the right way is so trivial and in fact very close to your code.
Just replace all the threading stuff with an AnimationTimer. Here is your updated main code. The rest just remains as before.

```
package week6code;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Bouncing Balls exercise starter
 *
 * @author Sam Scott
 */
public class BouncingBallsDoneRight extends Application {

    /**
     * Sets up the stage and starts the main thread. Your drawing code should
     * NOT go here.
     *
     * @param stage The first stage
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Bouncing Balls!"); // window title here
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 300); // canvas size here
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // This code starts an AnimationTimer which will run your animation
        AnimationTimer at = new AnimationTimer() {          
            Ball ball = new Ball(100, 50, -1, -1, 10, Color.RED);
            @Override
            public void handle(long arg0) {
                // draw screen 
                gc.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                gc.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
                ball.draw(gc);

                // moving
                ball.moveOneStep();

                // bouncing
                if (ball.getX() <= 0 || ball.getX() >= 400 - (ball.getSize() - 1)) {
                    ball.bounceX();
                }
                if (ball.getY() <= 0 || ball.getY() >= 300 - (ball.getSize() - 1)) {
                    ball.bounceY();
                }
            }
        };
        at.start();
    }

    /**
     * Launches the app
     *
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I tried to stay as close to your original code as possible. An even better solution for the task would be to use the scene graph and not the canvas.

Comment: That's true, it works for this example because all the animation state variables are wrapped up in the Ball object, but earlier in the course (when they have not yet touched OO) I don't think this would be possible. And it is also no longer a nice example of how to use a loop. Sometimes when you're trying to teach problem solving and building students up step by step, you have to be careful how you go so as not to overwhelm them with unnecessary detail, and sometimes you have to allow them to do things that upset purists. This is not an FX course, I'm just using FX to give them fun examples.

Comment: As teacher I understand Sam's reasons to keep it as simple as possible. Unfortunately experienced programmer without experiences with teaching real beginners cannot understand this reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that JavaFX is not thread-safe (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).
That is the reason of freeze. Each access, modification or drawing to UI should be done on UI thread.
That could be done with `Platform.runLater()`.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
  /*your code here*/
});
```